# How to fix invalid iterator error while using views pipeline and ranges adjacent_find in c++20

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20, std-ranges

I'm trying to check if all values in nested vector are same/unique. I wrote this program (simplified, but same error):

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/eMhdPcbf8)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectors_of_ints {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6}
    };

    auto get_vectors = [](const std::vector<int>& v) { return v; };
    auto get_ints = [](const int& i) { return i; };

    auto all_ints = vectors_of_ints
           | std::views::transform(get_vectors)
           | std::views::join
           | std::views::transform(get_ints);


    auto status = std::ranges::adjacent_find(all_ints, std::not_equal_to{}) != std::ranges::end(all_ints);

    return status;
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
<source>:22:44: error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__adjacent_find_fn) (std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, main()::<lambda(const std::vector<int>&)> > >, main()::<lambda(const int&)> >&, std::not_equal_to<void>)'
   22 |     std::cout << std::ranges::adjacent_find(all_ints, std::not_equal_to{}) != std::ranges::end(all_ints);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[...] // too long to post
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:594:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'forward_range<_Range>' [with _Range = std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >, main::._anon_112> >, main::._anon_113>&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/concepts:67:28: note:   'std::forward_iterator_tag' is not a base of 'std::input_iterator_tag'
   67 |     concept derived_from = __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Which concludes with: `std::forward_iterator_tag is not a base of std::input_iterator_tag`.

I would like to understand the problem I'm having here and how to fix that.

Comment: adjacent_find requires a forward iterator, you are providing it with an input iterator.

Comment: do you want the explicit copy?

Comment: @john at what point my iterator is set as input iterator? In simpler case as `0xbachmann` provided, the solution is working fine.

Comment: @masuo Don't quote me but my understanding is that using `transform` means that you have an input iterator. As a test try using your code on something that does only require an input iterator `std::ranges::count` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ranges__adjacent_find` requires a `forward_range` as input, but your `all_ints` is only an `input_range`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view):

> join_view models forward_range when:
>
> - `ranges::range_reference_t<V>` is a reference type, and
> - `V` and `ranges::range_reference_t<V>` each model forward_range.

`std::ranges::range_reference_t<Range>` is the return type of an element of a range of type `Range`. Because you transform `vector_of_ints` with your `get_vectors`, an element of the resulting range is `std::vector` and thus `std::ranges::range_reference_t` is not of reference type ([See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zEjoK6G59) ). **Note** this happens only because auto follows the [template argument deduction rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and does not deduce reference. If `get_vectors` to return a reference to `vector` instead, you can use [`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
auto get_vectors = [](const std::vector<int>& v) -> decltype(auto) { return v; };
```

or specify the return type of the lambda explicitly.

Or the simple

```
auto all_ints = vectors_of_ints | std::views::join;
```

works.

If you really want to copy the contents, consider creating a new vector from `all_ints`:

```
std::vector<int> all_ints_copy(all_ints.begin(), all_ints.end());
```

In C++23 `std::ranges::to` simplifies this process and mitigates all copies to the end:

```
auto all_ints_copy_to = vectors_of_ints
                    | std::views::join
                    | std::ranges::to<std::vector<int>>();
```

[See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vdYfhs567)

Comment: Simple example that you attached is not working, but adding extra `join`, like `auto all_ints = vectors_of_ints | std::views::join | std::views::transform(get_ints);` is indeed working fine.

I would like to learn, why adding extra pair of `join` and `transform` is breaking the solution -- as my real world example is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @masuo fixed the simple example and added explanation